# Enable/Disable checkboxes in Google Sheet

Tags: checkbox

I am currently making a checklist in `Google Sheet`.

I have check boxes in Column `A` and email address of the person in charge for Column `I`. I want the checkbox in say row 4 disabled if the user has not entered an email address in the next row (row 5) of Column `I`.

The same goes with the succeeding rows.

How could this be done?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are **not** a free coding service. Can you show us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: I have tried doing Data Validation but it didn't work.

Comment: You may want to edit your question for clarity. As it is, it is not answerable as a 'question about programming', which is what this site is about. Please show what language are you coding in (add a tag) and maybe a a bit of code showing what is it that you have tried.